# how to assign variables to a redirect header when processing a PHP form

Tags: php, variables, redirect, header, captcha

I have a form that I am validating via captcha.
I have an if statement.
If user enter wrong captcha, it tells it to go back.
else the page should re-direct to the following

```
  http://tre.emv3.com/D2UTF8?emv_tag=876020001C384269&emv_ref=EdX7CqkdLe_d8SA9MOPQNCffL0p6Hq3D-jmueKEyWsbQKbo&FIRSTNAME_FIELD=XXXXXXXXX&LASTNAME_FIELD=XXXXXXXXX&DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD=XXXXXXXXX&EMAIL_FIELD=XXXXXXXXX&EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD=XXXXXXXXX&STORE_NAME_FIELD=XXXXXXXXX&
```

where every XXXXXXXX should be replaced by the variables from the form.
when I try the code below, the variables do not get replaced.
thank you for your help.

```
      <?php session_start(); ?>
      <?php 
      ob_start();
          date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
          include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/maininc/securimage/securimage.php';

          $securimage = new Securimage();
          if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
            // the code was incorrect
            // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

            // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
            echo "THIS IS WRONG.<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
            exit;
          }else{
           $FIRSTNAME_FIELD = $_POST['FIRSTNAME_FIELD'];
           $LASTNAME_FIELD = $_POST['LASTNAME_FIELD'];
           $DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD = $_POST['DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD'];
           $EMAIL_FIELD = $_POST['EMAIL_FIELD'];
           $EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD = $_POST['EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD'];
           $STORE_NAME_FIELD = $_POST['STORE_NAME_FIELD'];
           header('location: http://tre.emv3.com/D2UTF8?emv_tag=876020001C384269&emv_ref=EdX7CqkdLe_d8SA9MOPQNCffL0p6Hq3D-jmueKEyWsbQKbo&FIRSTNAME_FIELD=echo$FIRSTNAME_FIELD;&LASTNAME_FIELD=echo$LASTNAME_FIELD;&DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD=echo$DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD;&EMAIL_FIELD=echo$EMAIL_FIELD;&EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD=echo$EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD;&STORE_NAME_FIELD=echo$STORE_NAME_FIELD;&');
          }
      ob_end_flush();
      exit;
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of the echo's in your link and use header(" .. ") instead of '

read here why http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Thank you very much it solve my problems and gave ma a good night sleep. god bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Your string in the `header` function is surrounded by `'`. This will not convert variables. Change the surrounding `'` with `"` and also remove the echo command.

```
       header("location: http://tre.emv3.com/D2UTF8?emv_tag=876020001C384269&emv_ref=EdX7CqkdLe_d8SA9MOPQNCffL0p6Hq3D-jmueKEyWsbQKbo&FIRSTNAME_FIELD=$FIRSTNAME_FIELD&LASTNAME_FIELD=$LASTNAME_FIELD&DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD=$DATEOFBIRTH_FIELD&EMAIL_FIELD=$EMAIL_FIELD&EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD=$EMVCELLPHONE_FIELD&STORE_NAME_FIELD=$STORE_NAME_FIELD");
```